# How can I install ssl certificate in tomcat server in Windows Server?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have a file with extension(.p7s) and four files with extension(.crt) from Certified Authority. How can I install SSL by using only these files?

Answer (score 2):

Use Java keytool utility to manage your  SSL certificates in a Java keystore. Refer to this Tomcat documentation to learn how to create a Java keystore and install SSL certificate  for  Tomcat.

[Tomcat documentation](http://randomrack.in/blog/learning/9655/Tomcat-SSL-Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Java [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) utility to manage your certificates in a Java keystore. Have a look at [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) Tomcat documentation to learn how to create a Java keystore for use with Tomcat.